# CoinGecko API data undefined after re-render React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to render data from the [CoinGekco API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api) in my React component. It works on first render but if I leave the page or refresh, coin.market_data is undefined.  I also tried passing `coin` to the `useEffect()` dependency array and that didn't work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../utils/axios";
import CoinDetail from "./CoinDetail";

function CoinPagePage() {
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCoin = () => {
      const coinid = window.location.pathname.split("/").splice(2).toString();
      axios
        .get(`/coins/${coinid}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setCoin(res.data);
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };
    getCoin();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <CoinDetail current_price={coin.market_data.current_price.usd} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CoinPagePage;
```

Comment: The problem is probably with the `window.location.pathname.split("/").splice(2).toString()`, can you `console.log(coinid)` and check if it always returns a valid id? I suggest trying `React Router` and get the id from param

Comment: console logged `coinid` and it does return a valid id always. On my main page where I have all the coins, I take the coin id from that API call and use it for my link to the individual coin page so the id in the URL should always be valid. It always returns the correct API data for the correct coin I clicked when it works. It just seems like it's not making the API call again when I refresh or leave the page and come back to the page because the data is then undefined

Comment: You will have to do the fetch inside the `<CoinDetail>` component. Pass `coinid` to the coindetail component as prop and move the fetch code inside the coindetail. Because price is passed as a prop to the detail page, it doesn't send a request again when refreshing.

Comment: So I did that and I still have the same issue. What's weird is if do `{coin.name}` it works every time. As soon as I try to get an object inside an object(like anything inside the `market_data` object), I get undefined on refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GET request` only happens when rendering the parent page. Re-rendering the child component will not run the fetch code again. Instead of passing `current_price` as a prop to your `<CoinDetail>` component, you could try passing `coinid` and doing the fetch inside your detail page.

That way, when the page is refreshed, the `request` will be executed again.

### Edit

If you try to access a not existing property on an object, your application will crash. What you could do to prevent this from happening is checking if the `request` is done, before trying to access the property.

One way you could do this by setting the initial state value to `null`

```js
const [coin, setCoin] = useState(null);
```

Then, above the main `return`, you could check if the value is `null`, if it is, return some sort of loading screen

```js
if(coin === null) return <LoadingScreen />;

// main render
return (
  <div>
    <CoinDetail current_price={coin.market_data.current_price.usd} />
  </div>
);
```

This way, when the fetch is done, the state gets updated and the page will re-render and show the updated content.

Comment: Passed `coinid` as a prop to `<CoinDetail>` and moved the fetch inside of that component. Still getting the same behavior. `{coin.market_data.current_price.usd}` shows the data on first render, then undefined errors until that part of code is removed. If I paste it back in and hit save while still on the page, it shows the price. Leave the page and come back, or refresh, undefined. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: [Here](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/binancecoin) is the API data I am working with

Comment: In the detail component, try logging your coinid prop, is it ever undefined? In Chrome dev tools (F12), under network tab, try looking what requests are made to the API

Comment: coinid prop is never undefined and checking dev tools network the API request is missing as long as `{coin.market_data.current_price.usd}` is there. If I take that out and leave `{coin.name}` it makes the request to the API every single refresh.

Comment: Could you try `console.log(coin)`, if you have a sandbox link I would like to take a look

Comment: I think that's the issue right there. I did `console.log(coin)` and it always shows up as an empty `Object{ }` for a few seconds, and then the object filled with my data comes through. I supposed I need to check if `coin` exists first?

Comment: Normally, if you save the `res.data` in a state variable, the page should rerender, try setting the initial state value to `useState(null)`, then above your return, type `if(coin == null) return <p>Loading...</p>`

Comment: That's it right there, everything works now! Thank you :) I hope you have a fantastic day

Comment: @tim-carey-code updated the answer, glad your issue is fixed.